# TypeError: must be real number, not none type plus more errors

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, nonetype

Oh, goodness. I've become a regular here. I have all of my code but it's weird because I'm trying my best but I cannot seem to get it to work. I've tried rewriting parts of it and even making minor changes but it just won't work. At all.

```
"""
WeeklyPay.py helps calculate the gross pay of multiple employees based on the hours they worked and their hourly rate
"""

    def main():
        """
        call other modules to get the work done
        :return: None
        """
        total_gross_pay = 0
        total_hours_worked = 0
        employee_quantity = 0

        company_employee = input("Did the employee work this week? Y or y for yes: ")
        while company_employee == "y" or "Y":
            employee_quantity += 1
            name, hours, rate = get_info()
            gross_pay = caculate_gross_pay(hours, rate)
            pay_stub(name, hours, rate, gross_pay)

            total_gross_pay += gross_pay
            total_hours_worked += hours

            company_employee = input("Have more employees worked? Y or y for yes: ")
        show_summary(employee_quantity, total_hours_worked, total_gross_pay)


    def get_info():
        """
        This module gets the needed info from employees
        :return: name, hours_worked, pay_rate
        """
        name = input("Enter the employee's name: ")
        hours_worked = float(input("How many hours did the employee work? "))
        pay_rate = float(input("What is the employee's hourly pay rate? "))
        return name, hours_worked, pay_rate


    def caculate_gross_pay(hours_worked, pay_rate):
        """
        Hours above 40 will be paid time and a half (1.5)
        :param hours_worked:
        :param pay_rate:
        :return: gross_pay
        """
        if hours_worked > 40:
            gross_pay = 40 * pay_rate + (hours_worked - 40) * 1.5 * pay_rate
        else:
            gross_pay = pay_rate * hours_worked

            return gross_pay

    def pay_stub(name, hours_worked, pay_rate, gross_pay):
        """
        This module prints the pay_stub
        :param name:
        :param hours_worked:
        :param pay_rate:
        :param gross_pay:
        """
        print("Employee Name: " + name)
        print("Hours Worked: %.2f"%hours_worked)
        print("Hourly Pay Rate: $%.2f"%pay_rate)
        print("Gross Pay: $%.2f"%gross_pay)


    def show_summary(employee_quantity, total_hours, total_pay):
        """
        :param employee_quantity:
        :param total_hours:
        :param total_pay:
        :return: None
        """
        print("Pay Summary ")
        print("Total number of employees: {}".format(employee_quantity))
        print("Total hours worked by all employees {}".format(total_hours))
        print("Total pay given to employees ${:,.2f}".format(total_pay))

   main()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inge scool/PycharmProjects/Week1/WeeklyPay.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/inge scool/PycharmProjects/Week1/WeeklyPay.py", line 20, in main
    pay_stub(name, hours, rate, gross_pay)
  File "C:/Users/inge scool/PycharmProjects/Week1/WeeklyPay.py", line 65, in pay_stub
    print("Gross Pay: $%.2f"%gross_pay)
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

I've tried searching online and keep getting stuff about integers with NoneType but is isn't fully applicable to what I'm doing. I'm adding numbers?

Comment: @Carcigenicate now I'm in a loop for asking fro employee info

Comment: Try just `print()`ing out `gross_pay` in the `pay_stub` method and see what it spits out. That's a good way to start debugging and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```py
   def caculate_gross_pay(hours_worked, pay_rate):
        """
        Hours above 40 will be paid time and a half (1.5)
        :param hours_worked:
        :param pay_rate:
        :return: gross_pay
        """
        if hours_worked > 40:
            gross_pay = 40 * pay_rate + (hours_worked - 40) * 1.5 * pay_rate
        else:
            gross_pay = pay_rate * hours_worked
        return gross_pay ## remove indent here
```

Following the traceback you can see that `gross_pay` is returned inside an `if/else`, and only returns if the else is run. Simply unindent it and it should work.

Comment: There is only one comment for me, and it is by the author